# Undefined Variable, Populate in a SELECT form. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5.7, populate

I'm trying to populate in a Select form, however I'm getting "Undefined Variable: populate" error and I was thinking that it might have something to do with my Routes but I don't know how since my form is a Modal. I have tried to put my populate code in the Index and it worked! But I'm trying to use my index function for something else so I created another function `populate`

Here's my Code for my Controller:

```
public function populate()
{
    $populate = \DB::table('residents')->where('resident_status', 'Active')->pluck('resident_fname', 'resident_lname');
    $populate = Collect($populate)->toArray();
    return view('forms.addComplaintsModal')->with('populate', $populate);
```

Here's my code for the Form:

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                {!! Form::select('complainee_name', $populate, ['class'=> 'form-control'])  !!}
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: can you show us your routes?

Comment: @Miguel Cruz I did nothing with my routes, cause I have no idea what to put in it.

Comment: That's why it's not working...

Comment: @Miguel Cruz then what would I put in the routes? I'm sorry if I sound too dumb, But I absolutely have no idea what to put in there, I'm using a Modal for my forms. Shall it be Routes::get('what shall I put in here?', 'NameOfController@populate');

Comment: What's your controller name and the page where your form is?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm absolutely new to Laravel.

Comment: My form is named : AddComplaintsModal.blade.php while my controller is BpsoController.php

Comment: Try something like this: Route::get('/populate', 'BpsoController@populate');

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Controller

```
public function populate()
{
    $populate = \DB::table('residents')->where('resident_status', 'Active')->pluck('resident_fname', 'resident_lname')->toArray();
    return view('forms.addComplaintsModal', compact('populate'));
}
```

Blade file

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
     {!! Form::select('complainee_name', $populate, null, ['class'=> 'form-control'])  !!}
</div>
```

You also forgot 3rd argument of `Form::select` which is used for selected value and it is required